# Second ResultSet.next() reporting true but while loop existing

Tags: sql, jdbc

While using a JDBC connection I am trying to perform 2 SELECT statements. The first returns a single record from a table (SQL_IBGN), and the second is designed to return multiple records from another table (SQL_ITXN) using a column (BGNREF) from the first query.

I have separate Statement and ResultSet objects for each query.

Code for Query 1:

```
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "SELECT BGNREF..... FROM SQL_IBGN WHERE BGNREF LIKE '2306009';";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    String bgnref = null;
    while (rs.next()) {
        G1SQL_IBGN g1rec = new G1SQL_IBGN();
        bgnref = rs.getString(1);
        g1rec.setBGNREF(bgnref);
    }
```

Code for Query 2:

```
        if (bgnref != null) {
        Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement();
        String sql1 = "SELECT ACT_DESC...... SQL_ITXN WHERE BGNREF LIKE '"
                + bgnref + "';"; // Execute the SELECT statement ResultSet
        ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(sql1); // Get result of first five records
        while (rs1.next()) {
            G1SQL_ITXN g1itxn = new G1SQL_ITXN();
            g1itxn.setACT_DESC(rs1.getString(1));
        }
    }
```

The first query is returning a single record, however even though rs1.next() = true, the second while loop, while (rs1.next()) is not executed.

Comment: How do you know it isn't executed? You're allocated an object in the loop, setting a parameter on it and then it goes out of scope, shouldn't you be attaching it to something? Also, I think using like without a pattern is the same as equals. Learning how to use bound parameters in queries would also be a good idea.

Comment: I know the G1SQL_ITXN g1txn = new.... isn't executed because when I debug it the code jumps from the while (rs1.next()) { line to the closing brace (}). The LIKE is being used with the code line below which is concatenating the contents of bgnref to the sql1 String variable and then appending ';.

Comment: Have you tried running (not debugging) it with a `System.out.println("Hello");` inside the second loop? How do you know rs1.next() is true?

Comment: I used System.out.println(rs1.next()) above the WHILE loop and it echoed true.  System.out.println("hello"); inside the WHILE loop does not echo.

Comment: The trouble with this is that your `System.out.println(rs1.next());` consumes a row. If you're going to debug it like that you need to do an `rs1.previous();` afterwards (and hope that your recordset supports rewind).

Comment: Laurence - Thanks, I hadn't realised that System.out.println(rs1.next()); would consume the row. Sorted now.